# TStringHelper is not returning the correct results

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I'm using the `TStringHelper` in a Win32 Application, but when I try to access a particular char or get a substring the values returned are not the same If I use the equivalent old string functions.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  i : Integer;
  s : string;
begin
  try
    i:=12345678;
    Writeln(i.ToString().Chars[1]);  // returns 2
    Writeln(i.ToString().Substring(1)); //returns 2345678

    s:=IntToStr(i);
    Writeln(s[1]); //returns 1
    Writeln(Copy(s,1,Length(s)));//returns 12345678
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

The question is Why the TStringHelper functions are not equivalent to the old string functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because all the methods and properties of the System.SysUtils.TStringHelper are zero based index, this helper was compiler with the [{$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS ON}](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Zero-based_strings_%28Delphi%29) directive. you can find more info in the [System.SysUtils.TStringHelper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper) documentation.

Answer (score 4):

The [`TStringHelper`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Chars) functions are 0-based, not 1-based. From the linked docs for `TStringHelper.Chars` (**emphasis mine**):

> Accesses individual characters in this **zero-based string**.

From the link for [`TStringHelper.SubString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Substring) (again, **emphasis mine**):

> Returns the substring starting at the position StartIndex and optionally ending at the position StartIndex + Length, if specified, from this **0-based string**.

The code sample from the `Chars` link also shows the loop running from `0` to `Length - 1`, instead of the usual `string` loop that runs from `1` to `Length(string)` (code comment mine):

```
var
  I: Integer;
  MyString: String;

begin
  MyString := 'This is a string.';

  for I:= 0 to MyString.Length - 1 do  // Note start and end of loop condition
    Write(MyString.Chars[I]);
end.
```

Comment: The whole reason `TStringHelper` was introduced in the first place was to create 0-based string operations without breaking backwards compatibility with existing code.  Embarcadero is trying to slowly move the RTL towards 0-based string handling everywhere.